# Context of Polymer Filter Expressions

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

What is the best way to reference the actual polymer element inside a filter expression? It seems like `this` refers to the parent `template` object. If I need to access the actual polymer element's properties in a filter, can I even do so? Is the element not completely created initially, making accessing the element irrelevant during the templating process?

**EDIT:** the filter is inside of a repeated template

simplified example:

```
<template repeat="{{item in items}}">
  <div>{{prop | filterMethod}}</div>
</template>
<script>
...
filterMethod : function(v){
  return this.someProp + v;
},
...
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have misunderstood your question, but when you define an expression inside an element, you have access to `this`:

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">
  <template>
    <template repeat="{{thing in things}}">
      <div>{{thing | reverse}}</div>
    </template>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      val: "foo",
      created: function() {
        this.things = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'XYZ'];
      },
      reverse: function(value) {
        return (this.val + " " + value).split('').reverse().join('');
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

This is the output:

```
CBA oof
FED oof
ZYX oof
```

You can try the example at http://jsbin.com/yuvoqu/edit

Comment: Sorry, it seems a fairly important piece was left out. The template is a repeated template. Updated the question.

Comment: right, ok...I see now I've been confused as to the actual object `this` is in the filter, as the console displays something that looks different to me, which I'm guessing has to do with the repeat...anyways it *does* work...thanks